# How much data transfer does a typical http request generate on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, network-protocols

I'm trying to assess what running a crawler off EC2 would cost. This [page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) says data transfer IN is free and data transfer OUT is not. So in case I make an `HTTP GET` request to some site, with GET header length, say, 200 bytes, and response of 20000 bytes how many bytes of outbound data transfer do actually get billed from my account? Is there a case study, or an explanation of how they measure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will measure it at the boundary between the network and the datacenter. Which means that TCP/IP overhead is probably involved in the packet overall packet size.

I don't think most people are looking at this as cost of processing and storing the data will become a concern long before bandwidth does.